# python setuptools installation in centos

Tags: centos, setuptools, python

i have to install mysqldb module of python in my centos server. i have 2 versions of python

```
1. 2.4.3 the default one
2. 2.6 which i installed
```

i want to install mysqldb module for 2.6 version of the python.
i installed it from [here](http://ben.timby.com/?p=123) but when i am on the line

```
python2.6 setup.py install
```

it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
from setuptools import setup, Extension
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

so i went for installing setup tools from [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#id6).using the command

```
setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
```

because i installed 2.6 python so i installed this rpm. but when i execute this command it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

but when i did locate command i do find the package and rpm installed for zlib.

```
/usr/share/doc/zlib-1.2.3
/usr/share/doc/zlib-1.2.3/README
/var/cache/yum/base/packages/zlib-devel-1.2.3-4.el5.x86_64.rpm
```

can any one please help me in this. I exactly want to install mysqldb module for python 2.6 i installed on my

```
/usr/local/bin/
```

directory. I searched net and tried everything. i also installed all

```
readline-devel
sqlite-devel
zlib-devel
openssl-devel
```

and tried again but no success. Now on every try it says that zlib installed nothing to do.(when i try it from yum).

any help or idea will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your python2.6 installation is compiled with zlib support.

Comment: i already compiled it and deleted the extracted folder and .tar file too month ago. now how can i re-compile it for this zlib ??

Comment: Exactly the same way you did it the first time.

Comment: Try with this for example: ./configure --with-zlib=/usr/include  --prefix=/your/prefix/choice

To be able to compile python with zlib support, you must have zlib-devel installed...from what you have wrote, you installed the zlib-devel package after configure/compile python2.6. So you need to recompile.

Comment: it is saying configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-zlib

Comment: i tried doing wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.6/Python-2.6.6.tgz
tar -zxvf Python-2.6.6.tgz
cd Python-2.6.6
./configure --with-zlib=/usr/include

Comment: It seems in this version it's integrated, so  if it finds the zlib libs, it will compile the module, e.g. there's no --with-zlib, try just recompile.